# Regex.Replace or String.Replace doesn't work for host URL in Linux environment

Tags: c#, linux, asp.net-core

**My Setup**
Development machine:

- Windows 10
- IIS express

Staging machine:

- Ubuntu 18.04
- Nginx

**My problem**
I have a simple, yet strange problem.
In the block of code below, I generate an email confirmation link. Now, I want to replace the domain of the generated URL with another one.

```
// class fields
        private readonly string _WebServerRelativeUrl = "https://www.specific-domain.com/account/";
        private readonly string _BingoServerRelativeUrl = "https://www.specific-domain.eu/api/v1/identity/";
        private readonly string _BingoLocalServerRelativeUrl = "https://localhost:44375/api/v1/identity/";


// code excerpt from confirm email method
var passwordResetLink = _urlHelper.Action("ResetPassword", "identity",
                new { email = appUser.Email, token, lang }, _httpRequest.HttpContext.Request.Scheme);

            var url = Regex.Replace(passwordResetLink, _BingoServerRelativeUrl, _WebServerRelativeUrl, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            if (_environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                url = Regex.Replace(passwordResetLink, _BingoLocalServerRelativeUrl, _WebServerRelativeUrl, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            }
```

On localhost, all works fine. The server generates a URL as follows:

```
https://localhost:44375/api/v1/identity/confirmemail?userId=abcd&token=abcd
```

And then the https://localhost:44375/api/v1/identity is successfully replaced with https://www.specific-domain.com/account/

However, in a production environment, the application is running on Ubuntu 18.04, behind Nginx with a specific domain. Now, this string replacement doesn't work when the application is in the production environment on the Linux VM.

I also tried the String.Replace() instead of the regex, the same result. What could be the issue?

Comment: Fix the title.  This is not a REGEX issue.  You connection is not completing.  It is a HTTPS issue.  More likely a TLS authentication issue that is used with HTTPS.  Use a sniffer an check the version of TLS that is being used in working and non working.  Five years ago the industry decided to eliminate TLS 1.0/1.1 due to security issues.  In June this year Microsoft did a security update on server and disabled TLS 1.0/1.1 and now requires TLS 1.2/1.3.  Not sure what you need to update.  The default TLS version is determined by your operating system (and kernel).

Comment: Add some logging to check what the translated URL looks like. Also, note that the '.' characters in the regex string have a special meaning and shuld thus be escaped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debugging this problem would require quite a bit of time. Found an easier solution by building the initially desired URL with the [Flurl library.](https://flurl.dev/) The solution requires less code.

```
var url = WebServerRelativeUrl
    .AppendPathSegment(ResetPassPath)
    .SetQueryParams(new
    {
         email = appUser.Email, token = token, lang = lang
    });
```

P.S I prefer this one over [UriBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uribuilder?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1) because it offers Fluent interface.